# Solving the geometry when projecting to a road with inclination

Tags: geometry

[image]

The figure above shows a beam projecting at a height *h* at angle *b* to the ground with a road inclination *a* degrees.

Assume *h*=8.3, *h0*=6.5, *h1*=1.8, *a*=5.3 degrees, *b*=20 degrees, I can work out the value of *y* and *z*.

If *h* and *a* stay the same, is it possible to work out the values of *h0*, *h1*, *y* and *z* when *b* is changed (e.g. 15 degrees)?

Comment: You assume that everything is as in the initial position. The problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Law of Sines says
$$
z=\frac{h\sin(\pi/2-a)}{\sin(a+b)}=\frac{h\cos(a)}{\sin(a+b)}
$$
and the definition of cosine says
$$
y=z\cos(b)
$$
The definition of sine says
$$
h_0=z\sin(b)
$$
and then
$$
h_1=h-h_0
$$